# error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'RequestInfo'

Tags: typescript, react-native, reactxp

I'm working in a ReactXP project where I must use React Native [native modules](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html).

So I've included the react-native types as a dev dependency.

My project does not compile right now with the following errors:

```
node_modules/@types/react-native/globals.d.ts(92,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'RequestInfo'.
node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts(8751,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'console'.
node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts(8759,18): error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'geolocation' must be of type 'Geolocation', but here has type 'GeolocationStatic'.
node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts(8762,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'navigator'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(15764,13): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable'navigator'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(15940,13): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable'console'.
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(15997,6): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'RequestInfo'.
18:17:44 - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

Following are my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.4.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
        "react-native": "^0.55.4",
        "react-native-windows": "^0.54.0",
        "reactxp": "^1.2.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react-native": "^0.55.16",
        "@types/webpack": "^4.1.3",
        "@types/node": "9.6.7",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.5",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "rnpm-plugin-windows": "^0.2.8",
        "source-map-loader": "^0.2.3",
        "ts-node": "^5.0.1",
        "tslint": "^5.9.1",
        "tslint-microsoft-contrib": "^5.0.3",
        "typescript": "^2.8.1",
        "webpack": "^4.5.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13"
    }
```

and tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "noResolve": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "reactNamespace": "RX",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "types": [
      "lodash",
      "react",
      "react-dom"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/ts/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Add `"skipLibCheck": true` in tsconfig.json

Ref: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/16825

Comment: This is the right thing to do indeed. I had to exit watch mode and restart tsc to see the change.

Comment: Though this just sort of masks the issue. The real solution would be for the DefinitelyTyped people to make their packages’ types compatible with each other.

Comment: I can confirm this works, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I added `"skipLibCheck": true` and `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to tsConfig.js.